# why doesn't this layout work? android

Tags: android, listview

I have this layout file as my main activity's layout. when I don't have the linear layout and the two textview in the middle, the list view worked. however, when i have them in the file, the view wont show the listview content. Can anyone tell whats the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout    
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/today_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"
            android:textSize = "20sp"
            android:paddingTop="12dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"

           >
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/today_total"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:textSize = "6sp"
            android:textColor="#4A4A4A"
            android:paddingTop="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just something else to keep in mind, the layout height of the listview "can't", be set to wrap_content as it doesn't have any children views yet (Android will measure the first 3 views when it can to determine a size) . Instead, set it to a value such as 0dip and Android will take care of sizing it.

Comment: thanks for the tip! i m quite new to android programming :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the LinearLayout is set to  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
 and the TextViews, well they take up the whole screeen because you set weights to them, so the actuall height of the TextViews does not get applied.

Change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout    
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/today_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"
            android:textSize = "20sp"
            android:paddingTop="12dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"

           >
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/today_total"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:textSize = "6sp"
            android:textColor="#4A4A4A"
            android:paddingTop="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks! i set the second linear layout to be horizontal,  i dont think that the two textview will fill up the height.

Comment: hmm.. i tried again, you are right about the textview. but if i dont set the layout_weight, the second textview doesnt get showed.

Comment: Keep the Layout as it is, just change the height of the child LinearLayout to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This will give each of your elements 1/3 of the screen height.  Play with the value of Layout_weight to change the amount of screen_height that each element occupies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/today_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:textColor="#dc6800"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        android:paddingTop="12dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"

       >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/today_total"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:textSize = "6sp"
        android:textColor="#4A4A4A"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```